# Can I see an example that shows the use of .arrays and push(unint x) method in solidity 0.6?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, arrays, solidity-0.6.x

I'm having problem to understand  why the method push() does't work on Remix using Solidity 0.6.

I have read the documentation about arrays fixed size and dynamic size
[doc reference](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#arrays)

for example in this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Prova
{

   function prova() public{

      uint[] memory array;
      array.push(4);

   }
}
```

I always get the error: :

> TypeError: Member "push" is not available in uint256[] memory outside
>   of storage.

Someone can show me sole example about arrays in solidity. 
I'm learning.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `.push` with a transient memory instance of an array. It has to be a storage variable.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Prova
{
   uint[] public array;

   function prova() public {
      array.push(4);
   }
}
```

Or, for giggles:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract Prova
{
   uint[] public array;

   function prova(uint number) public {
      array.push(number);
   }
}
```

It is declared globally, so `storage` is implied. I added `public` so you can inspect it with `array(uint row)`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok perfect, my problem was that I declared the array inside the function ...